# difference between calling System.gc() and process killed by system

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

What is the difference between

- `System.gc()` getting called inside an activity in Android app and
- Android system killing process for low memory ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are different in the sense that `System.gc()` invoke the garbage collector to start to run but it is not sure that it would run. If it finds no more memory then then it start to free the allocated memory.

> Android system killing process for low memory ?

If android find available free memory is low of the device then it tries to kill the long running process and free the associated memory

### Update

It is best not to call the `System.gc()` because android system own call this method when it finds there is no free memory.

Comment: The `OutOfMemoryError` (preceded by a last `System.gc()`) may happen to a foreground process (i.e. an activity currently on screen) but the Android system may decide to kill other processes (unused apps and long running services) to free up memory before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. Also there is no need to invoke `System.gc()` programmatically as the system already performs it from time to time and besides it is not even guaranteed to run in the first place.